# Reducir espacio de filas en un CardView

Tags: android, android-layout

Tengo un problema, al implementar un Cardview. es el código de mi layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_view_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_view_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_view_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/card_view_vertical"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_view_radius">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="176dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/card_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Pero al momento de correr la aplicación este es el resultado:

[image: Espacio entre Cardview]

La cuestion es: **¿Cómo elimino ese espacio?**

Comment: Es el layout del CardView, pero el código que crea los CardViews y el layout que los contiene sería importante lo agregaras.

Comment: Amigo no podemos ver tu imagen! De igual forma me imaginaré que buscas aunque puede que mi respuesta no sea la correcta porque no entiendo del todo tu duda.

Answer (score 0):

No entendí a queé necesitas quitarle los espacxios, pero si refieres a los magrenes del CardView solo con quitarle lo que dice dimensions jala. Saludos, si no es lo que buscas, aclaramé la pregunta o tu duda y con gusto te propongo otra solución.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_view_radius">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="176dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/card_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```